# Nintex Workflow simulation Environment

Tags: nintex-workflow

I'm new to Nintex Workflow product . I joined the community and I watched the tutorials about creating various workflows . My question is there any Nintex simulation environment I can work on or I must contact Nintex sales .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yea you have to contact Nintex sales from its official website